# How to 'activate' required after something changed in input (angular4)?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, required

I am developing my project with angular(4)

I want to make validation.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="someModel" required placeholder="some placeholder"/>
```

But it triggers immediately.

How can i trigger required  only after input was changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<input [(ngModel)]="someModel" required #someModel='ngModel' placeholder="some placeholder"/>
<div [hidden]="someModel.valid || someModel.pristine">
  Field is required
</div>
```

p.s. but you must have access to AbstractControl class.

Some other options might be `someModel.dirty` or `someModel.touched`, but according to your question, `pristine` is what you are looking for.

[AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#pristine)